# Django MultipleChoiceFilter disable checks for choices

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to add a filter for entities, which searches for list of values and return matching ones or empty list.

```
class DistributionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    survey = django_filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter("survey")
    ...
```

request looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/distributions/?survey=1&survey=2&isDefault=true
```

I am getting

```
{"survey":["Select a valid choice. 2 is not one of the available choices."]}
```

But I just want filtered values, and don't care about input values not present in db or choices.
How can I reach that?